# How does the data binding work in android?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Recently, I am learning data binding of android. I have known how to basic use it in android project. And then I want to learn deeply more about it:

- How does it work?
- what happen when I bind model with layout?

I have google the data binding principle, but the results that return of google almost just tell how to use it. 
Anybody known the principle? or some blog/ article about it?

Comment: Are you talking about downloading data and binding it to a layout? Such cases always make use of the android recycler view.

Comment: Emm..I want to learn the principle of data binding in android